# How to write persist in svelte?

Tags: local-storage, svelte, svelte-3, writable, svelte-store

I need to convert my store to a persisting store that uses a Localstorage to hold my data even if the user closes the browser. I have tried writing the code using Localstorage.setItem and getItem but unfortunately, It doesn't work properly. Can someone help me to write it in a proper way?

This is my code in App.svelte file

```
<script>
const storeInputFromUser = () => {
userId = Math.random();
let inputData = {
  id: userId,
  title: inputTitle, /* here I am taking input from input field. It works fine */
  text: inputText, /* here I am taking input from input field. It works fine */
};
inputTitle = '';
inputText = '';
database = [inputData, ...database];
DataStore.update(() => {
  return database;
});
</script>


//DataStore.js

import { writable } from "svelte/store";

const DataStore = writable(JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("data")) || {});
DataStore.subscribe(value => {
    localStorage.setItem("data", JSON.stringify(value));
    console.log(value);
});

export default DataStore;
```

This code can save data into the local storage but when I click refresh, the DIV I use to show the data becomes empty. The local storage still has the data

Comment: [Dean Fogarty - Transforming data to and from storage areas using Svelte custom stores](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=85Gc-i0ITf8) from the last Summit might help

Comment: Besides that, instead of using the `update` function in your code you could use `DataStore.set(database)` because you're not updating/modifying the actual store value or even use the shorter syntax `$Datastore = database` because you're inside a `.svelte` file

Comment: import { writable } from "svelte/store";


const DataStore = writable(JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("data")) || {});
DataStore.subscribe(value => {
    localStorage.setItem("data", JSON.stringify(value));
});

export default DataStore;

I edited my code. now another bug. This code can save data into the local storage but when I click refresh, the DIV I use to show the data becomes empty. The local storage still has the data
@Corrl

Comment: Instead of putting your modified code inside the comment, it would be better if you would update your question. And it's always helpful to put up a [REPL](https://svelte.dev/repl/hello-world?version=3.44.1) with your code

Comment: Finally, I found the bug brother. I used a variable to check whether if there is data or not in the object which is fetched from the store. 
`const dataPresent = false;`
then in the function above mentioned, There was a statement that change the state of this variable to be true.
`const storeInputFromUser = () => {...
......
dataPresent = true;

{#if dataPresent}
<div>...code that shows data...</div>
{/if}
`
So whenever I refresh the page this variable will become false.
So the DIV I used will be hidden until the next time it becomes true.

Thank you

Comment: @prasobh Can you write your own solution as an answer and then accept it? That way this question does not show up as unresolved in StackOverflow.